# Show that there is a $\mathfrak B$ basis of a $n -$ dimmensional vector Space $V$ such that $[T]_{\mathfrak B} = A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an n-dimmensional vector space $V$ over $K$ and let $T \in \ L(V)$ such that $(T - \lambda I)^n = 0 ,$ $ \ \lambda \ \in K$ and $(T - \lambda I)^{n-1} \neq 0$. Prove that there is a basis $\mathfrak B$ of $V$ such that

$$ [T]_{\mathfrak B}= A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \lambda & 1& &  &    &0\\
         & \ddots& \ddots & & & \\
         & & & & &\\
        & & &  \ddots&  &1 \\
        0 & & & & & \lambda \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I know that $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $T$

Please give me hint how to solve.

Thank you

Comment: Look for Jordan normal form. This is a very special case of said form. Generally $\mathfrak B$ will contain $n$ generalized eigenvectors of $T$ for it's only eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: @ Alex : I will try

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Show that if $\;v\in V\;$ is a vector s.t. $\;(T-\lambda I)^{n-1}v\neq 0\;$ , then

$$\;B:=\left\{v,\,(T-\lambda I)v,\,(T-\lambda I)^2v,\ldots,(T-\lambda I)^{n-1}v\right\}\;$$

is a basis of $\;V\;$, for example by an inductive process:

$$0=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i(T-\lambda I)^kv\stackrel{\text{apply}\,(T-\lambda I)^{n-1}}\implies 0=a_0(T-\lambda I)^{n-1}v\implies\ldots$$

Now, wrt $\;B\;$ , we get that

$$[T-\lambda I]_B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&\ldots&0\\
0&0&1&0&\ldots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\ddots&1\\
0&0&0&0&\ldots&0\end{pmatrix}^t$$

Comment: @Om Thanks for the editing. It looks better now.